# Issue with POST request between javascript and Flask running on AWS lambda

Tags: python, database, flask, aws-lambda, server

So I recently build a python app that runs in terminal and decided to make it into a web app. The premise of app is take in user input... do some stuff and spit out a result. The user will make a decision on what to do next by inputting something new into the program.

I made a website with javascript that gathers the user's input... and when they hit enter, it makes a POST request to my Flask app. The app runs on that code and updates some variables in the Flask app in which the javascript subsequently retrieves with a GET request and updates the site accordingly.

I initially used Global python variables to update values across the Flask app, but later found out this is terrible idea when actually deploying due to not being thread safe. Indeed the app ran without flaw when done locally, but when deployed to AWS, did not work.

I updated the app to use a Flask cache, and again this worked locally, and further worked when running `threaded = True` and `processes=10` in `app.run()`. These changes caused the local build to crash when using global variables... so I thought this would have worked. But it did not. The AWS log shows that certain variables in the cache remain to be `None` even though they should have been updated in the cache by a pervious POST request.

This is my first time using Flask and AWS. Here is my code.

**common.py**

```
from flask_caching import Cache
cache = Cache()
```

**app.py** (the wordle module is script, just same functions I used in this file)

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    request,
    redirect,
    flash,
    url_for,
    current_app,
)
from wordle import *
import time
import json
from common import cache

app = Flask(__name__)
cache.init_app(app=app, config={"CACHE_TYPE": "filesystem",'CACHE_DIR': '/tmp'})

cache.set("frequencyWeights", commonWordWeighting())
cache.set("myWordList", getWordsFromFile("allowed_words.txt"))



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        cache.set("uGuess", request.form['userGuess'])
        cache.set("uPattern", request.form['userPattern'])
        
    return render_template("wordle.html")



@app.route('/restart', methods=['POST'])
def restart():
    if request.method == "POST":
        cache.set("myWordList", getWordsFromFile("allowed_words.txt"))
    return 'restarted'


@app.route('/getpythondata')
def get_python_data():
    time.sleep(1)

    if len(cache.get("myWordList")) != 1:
        myWordList = cache.get("myWordList")
        
        updatedWordList = getResultantWords(cache.get("uGuess").lower(), cache.get("uPattern"), myWordList)

        cache.set("myWordList", updatedWordList)

        rankings = rankedChoices(cache.get("myWordList"), cache.get("frequencyWeights"))

        topGuesses = {}
        i = 1
        for word, bits in rankings.items():
            topGuesses[i] = [word, bits]
            i = i + 1
            if i > 3:
                break            
        print(topGuesses)
    return json.dumps(topGuesses)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, processes=10)
```

**PART of JS file... executed when "Enter" is pressed**

```
// Send JS variables 'guess' and 'pattern' to Flask app 
$.post( "/", {
       userGuess: guess,
       userPattern: pattern 
});

// Retrieve whatever '/getpythondata' in Flask app returns
$.get("/getpythondata", function(data) {
      let myres = $.parseJSON(data)
};
```

My issues lies in `updatedWordList = getResultantWords(cache.get("uGuess").lower(), cache.get("uPattern"), myWordList)` where the log says `cache.get("uGuess")` is `None`. Again, the code as is works when I deploy the app on my local machine... but the described error arrises in the AWS lambda logs (The app builds and deploys normally).

**Update: AWS Log**

```
* Running on http://169.254.76.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
START RequestId: f87dc79c-f2e1-4ab1-ab9f-7da8dbb0ba15 Version: $LATEST
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2022 17:43:02] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
END RequestId: f87dc79c-f2e1-4ab1-ab9f-7da8dbb0ba15
REPORT RequestId: f87dc79c-f2e1-4ab1-ab9f-7da8dbb0ba15  Duration: 158.28 ms     Billed Duration: 1327 msMemory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 107 MB Init Duration: 1167.80 ms
[2022-03-20 17:43:03,721] ERROR in app: Exception on /getpythondata [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "app.py", line 47, in get_python_data
updatedWordList = getResultantWords(cache.get("uGuess").lower(), cache.get("uPattern"), myWordList)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2022 17:43:03] "GET /getpythondata HTTP/1.1" 500 -
END RequestId: e601d39e-fd07-4c5a-8ce4-b54cada69905
REPORT RequestId: e601d39e-fd07-4c5a-8ce4-b54cada69905  Duration: 1064.56 ms    Billed Duration: 1065 msMemory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 107 MB
```

Comment: Why are you using cache to store user data? That's amazingly unsafe, I would recommend using a simple Database like SQLite to store and use data.

Comment: Lambda in-memory cache stored in /tmp is to be volatile - `/tmp` is not a cache location.

Comment: @SumantAgnihotri Was just following a solution I saw on a different post blindly. Ill take a look into SQLite, would I not run into the same issue with the POST request? Just seems to me that something with how AWS is running the POST is causing the issue.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Any alternatives, sorry for my lack of knowledge this is all new to me? If /tmp is volatile, is it reasonable to assume thats why im having the POST issue? Could JS be correctly sending the POST to the cache on AWS, but the volatility causes an erase or rewrite , so on the GET request, there's nothing there?

Comment: @tjoab Not sure why but for cache, take a look at [Elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/)